# Angular Material not releasing DOM nodes/Js event listeners

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, angular-material, google-chrome-devtools, material-components-web

When I visit the [Material Components Demo page](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) and switch between the pages (e.g. *Autocomplete* and *Badge*), I can see in the Chrome dev-tools Performance monitor, that the number of DOM nodes and JS event listeners constantly increases.

Example:

- I open [Overview](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) (in an incognito window, so that there are no other chrome-extensions active)

  - on the Memory tab start a garbage collection (GC)
  - DOM Nodes ~1800 / JS Event listeners ~400
- now click on *Badge* in the left-hand side-menu & start GC

  - DOM Nodes ~2400/ JS Event listeners ~500
- Back to *Overview* & start GC

  - DOM Nodes ~3500/ JS Event listeners ~700

Note: also memory increases when we visit multiple pages and then start a GC

[image]

Shouldn't a garbage collection free the dom-nodes of the previous page?
Or is this a memory leak in the Material Components library (or maybe in the demo app)?

I ask because we also see this in our production app (which is large) and there it seems to have a severe performance impact.

Comment: SPA (Single-Page Application) means it uses the same page, the navigation is faked via history.pushState, so you have to find the code that doesn't release references to the old DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't a garbage collection free the dom-nodes of the previous page?

**Yes**. The garbage collector will free all DOM-nodes, that are not referenced anymore.
So in a well-behaved application/library switching from one route to another should not leak any memory and the `Performance monitor` tab should show the exact same numbers as before.

BUT: there may be good reasons in some cases to keep references to DOM nodes, e.g. maybe the library uses some sort of cache

> Or is this a memory leak in the Material Components library (or maybe in the demo app)?

Also **yes**. It seems that the Material Components library has memory leak issues:
Here are some open issues:

- [bug: Memory Leaks on several material components ? #19010](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19010)
- [bug(tree): tree memory leak in ivy #22094](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22094)
- [Mat-Dialog: Possible memory leak when dialog includes textarea, input, etc. #20595](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20595)
- [Animations with HostBinding used within Sidenav. Leaks detached DOM nodes #15225](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15225)
- [Ripple DOM elements are not garbage collected #15322](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/15322)
- [[Tooltip] Memory leak #8989](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8989)
- [[Sidenav] Memory leak when used inside router-outlet #8862](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8862)

Also the Angular Ivy renderer causes memory-leaks:

- [**ngContext** magnifies native Chrome memory leaks #41047](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41047)

**Stackblitz** hint:
I was not able to reproduce some issues on Stackblitz (i.e. I saw the memory leaks locally, but the same code on Stackblitz worked). The reason was, that Ivy was deactivated on Stackblitz (but my local ng-cli had Ivy activated by default). We can activate Ivy in the Stackblitz settings:
[image]

**Chrome-Dev-Tools** hint:
Before starting a garbage collection we should:

- remove all breakpoints
- clear the console (the messages may contain references which will keep them from being garbage collected.
- avoid chrome extension: use an incognito window or even better a new empty chrome-profile